# Joint probability function of dependent uniform and exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The output of a process is $XY^3$, where $X$ and $Y$ are mutually dependent. $Y$ is $\sim U(0,2)$ and if $Y=y$, $X$ is exponential with mean $y$. What is the expected output of the process?

I realize that the $E[XY^3]$ is the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty XY^3 f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$,
 but I'm not sure what my joint distribution function $P[XY^3]$ is?

Comment: $\operatorname{E}(XY^3)$ is not $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty XY^3 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy;$ rather, it is $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xy^3 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy.$ Capital $X$ is the random variable; lower-case $x$ is what goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in this integral. Without being careful about which is which, how would you understand something like $\Pr(X\le x)\text{?} \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Given the event $Y=y$, you have
$$
\operatorname{E}(XY^3 \mid Y=y) = \operatorname{E}(Xy^3\mid Y=y) = y^3 \operatorname{E}(X\mid Y=y) = y^3 \cdot y = y^4.
$$
So then you need the expected value of $Y^4$:
$$
\operatorname{E}(Y^4) = \int_0^2 y^4 \left( \frac 1 2 \, dy \right) = \cdots.
$$

This is an instance of the law of total expectation:
$$
\operatorname{E}(XY^3) = \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(XY^3\mid Y)) = \operatorname{E}(Y^4).
$$